# Use of existentials

Tags: haskell

I am reading through this excellent paper ["Functional Programming with Structured Graphs, Bruno C. d. S. Oliveira"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2012/graphs.pdf) ([some video here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtQGh5oemhkw&ei=WkPwUOy5Huiy0QHE1oCgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEa4XoYzjfHQtBnzblM4fNp-pauHA&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.dmQ)) and I'm trying to implement all the structures as I go. I'm struggling with the use of existentials. Although the author mentions Haskell throghout, it seems the types are more easily expressed in Coq or Agda. How can I make this compile? Thanks.

#### Code

```
data PStream a v = Var v
                 | Mu (v -> PStream a v)
                 | Cons a (PStream a v)

data Stream a = forall v. Pack {pop :: PStream a v} 


foldStream :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> b
foldStream f k (Pack s) = pfoldStream s
    where pfoldStream (Var x)     = x
          pfoldStream (Mu g)      = pfoldStream (g k)
          pfoldStream (Cons x xs) = f x (pfoldStream xs)
```

#### Errors

```
error:
 Couldn't match type `v' with `b'
      `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a pattern with constructor
            Pack :: forall a v. PStream a v -> Stream a,
          in an equation for `foldStream'
          at C:\...\StructuredGraph.hs:17:17
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            foldStream :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> b
          at C:\...\StructuredGraph.hs:17:1
    Expected type: PStream a b
      Actual type: PStream a v
    In the first argument of `pfoldStream', namely `s'
    In the expression: pfoldStream s
```

Comment: MFlamer, I added some links (to the paper and a video on some of the content).  In the process I messed up your spelling of 'excellent' in the first line, sorry about that.  Could you correct? I don't want to submit such a minor edit to the edit queue.  Thanks.  Cool question, BTW, although I'm not up to speed enough to give an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an existential type, but it looks like the type mentioned in the paper is universal (though I haven't read it beyond the definition of `Stream`).

There's a big difference between

```
newtype Stream a = forall v. Pack { pop :: PStream a v }
```

and

```
newtype Stream a = Pack { forall v. pop :: PStream a v }
```

The former doesn't seem very useful for this type, because you have no way of knowing what `v` is. The latter makes your code compile.

Comment: That's it. I guess its time to learn the difference between "universal type" and "existential type". Thanks.

Comment: Hah, you beat me to it.  (Although the first `newtype` definition is illegal.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp: True, GHC doesn't accept it. I'm not sure that it should be illegal, though -- is an existential newtype necessarily a problem, if it doesn't have any class constraints?

Comment: @shachaf it is if your core language is based on universal only system F + boxed ADTs (including boxed existentials).  In such a language an existential newtype has nothing to erase to.

Answer (score 4):

So, what do you think the type of this (partial) function is?

```
pfoldStream (Var x) = x
```

It's simple:

```
pfoldStream :: Stream a v -> v
```

Your `foldStream f k` operation basically computes `pfoldstream . pop`.  What would the type be?

```
-- this is wrong
pfoldstream . pop :: PStream a -> v
```

You can't do that.  You can't just return the type from inside an existential.  Note how there's a `v` on the right side.  How do we know what the correct `v` is?  We don't, because `v` is existentially qualified: the only information that the type checker has is that the type `v` exists, it has no information about whether that type is equal to `b`.

I can give a simpler illustration:

```
data E = forall a. E a
unpack (E x) = x
```

The type of `unpack` is not expressable in Haskell's type system, and that's basically what you're asking for.  The type would be `unpack :: E -> x`, but not for *any* x (x is not universally quantified), but for a *specific* x (x is existentially quantified).

### Fixing the problem

The next problem is "How do I make it compile?"  That's not the problem -- the problem is that the request is ill-specified.  I don't know what you want any more than the compiler does.  I can suggest one way to make it compile:

```
foldStream :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> PStream a b -> b
foldStream f k s = pfoldStream s
    where pfoldStream (Var x)     = x
          pfoldStream (Mu g)      = pfoldStream (g k)
          pfoldStream (Cons x xs) = f x (pfoldStream xs)
```

This gets rid of the existential qualifier, but I don't know how else to do it and I'm guessing it's not what you want.  An alternative way to make it compile is to replace the code with a function that plays "O Canada" through the user's speakers, but I suspect that is even less similar to what you want than the above code.

### Reading the paper

I looked at the paper and I don't think the type is supposed to be existential: I think you're supposed to use higher order types.  So instead of the existential type:

```
data Stream a = forall v. Pack {pop :: PStream a v}
```

We are really looking at the rank 2 type:

```
type Stream a = forall v. Stream a v
```

You can see in section 4.1 the way that the `v` variable is used to feed a stream into itself.  The reason this is universal is because it allows the consumer of the stream to use any type for `v`, therefore, `v` does not need to appear in the signature for `foldStream`.

Comment: Should "pfoldStream :: Stream a v -> v" above be "pfoldStream :: PStream a v -> v"? Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: @MFlamer: I can't keep `PStream` and `Stream` straight in my head, because "P" doesn't mean anything to me.  If you want to figure out where my errors are, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: The error was just 1 letter and S.O. wont let me make a change of less than 5. I understood your point and it was enlightening.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone seems to have answered at once.  I was just going to make the point that GADT syntax, as with `Str` below, always makes this more intelligible to me -- in this case why `foldStream` is hopeless with the quantifier the other way.  I have a quasi-readable version of the code from the paper, so I put it up here:  https://github.com/applicative/structured_graphs

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes#-}
data PStream a v = Var v
                 | Mu (v -> PStream a v)
                 | Cons a (PStream a v)
ones :: PStream Int v
ones = Cons (1 :: Int) ones

data Stream a where P :: forall a  . (forall v . PStream a v) -> Stream a
```

-- i.e. we use a (hard to construct) v-independent PStream a v -- an item of type `forall v . PStream a v` to make a `Str a`. So `P ones` for `ones` defined as  above, because I didn't use v to  define it. By contrast, with your

```
data Stream a where P :: forall a v .      PStream a v        -> Stream a
```

the type of `P` would let us construct a `Str a` with any old a and v you like and even the type of v will be invisible in the resulting `Str a`. So `P "Hello"` would be valid member of this type.  So good luck extracting x below, when the type b is specialized to `Int` rather than `String`:

```
foldStream  :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stream a -> b
foldStream f k = pfoldStream . pop
    where pfoldStream (Var x)     = x
          pfoldStream (Mu g)      = pfoldStream (g k)
          pfoldStream (Cons x xs) = f x (pfoldStream xs)
          pop (P x) = x
```

With the first (intended) declaration of `Stream`, the values are hard to construct, but easy to use. With the other ("existential") declaration it is easy to construct a value but hard to use it, since the underlying type is 'hidden'. You were running into this difficulty of using such a value  in attempting to define `pfoldStream`.